# How to define manual colors for text on individual facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to define manual colors for text on individual facets created by ggplot. But the code is assigning random colors.

I have included the code I tried to get the colors right.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))

dat_text <- data.frame(
  label = c("4 cylinders", "6 cylinders", "8 cylinders"),
  cyl   = c(4, 6, 8),
  cl = c("red", "blue", "black"),
  x     = c(20, 27.5, 25),
  y     = c(4, 4, 4.5)
)

p + geom_text(
  data    = dat_text,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, colour= cl)
)
```

The code is working except it is giving random colors instead of assigned colors.

Comment: They're not random; see the docs at `?scale_color_discrete` for the explanation of how categorical variables are assigned colors by default. If you want different colors, you have to tell your code that: since you have color names in the data already, the easiest thing to do is add `scale_color_identity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scale_color_manual` to manually set the colors:

```
dat_text <- data.frame(
  label = c("4 cylinders", "6 cylinders", "8 cylinders"),
  cyl   = c(4, 6, 8),
  cl = c("A", "B", "C"),
  x     = c(20, 27.5, 25),
  y     = c(4, 4, 4.5)
)

p + geom_text(
  data    = dat_text,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, colour= cl)
) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue","black"))
```

[image]

Note that the order is the alphabetical order of the levels, that's why I set the levels to A, B, C.

You probably don't want a legend for the text, so remove it:

```
p + geom_text(
  data    = dat_text,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, colour= cl), show.legend = FALSE
) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue","black"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can plot them all on the same plot, and just change the colour of the points.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars) +
  geom_point(data = mt, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = factor(mt$cyl))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "black")) +
  labs(color = "# of cylinders:")
```

[image]